# Asset precompile missing standalone javascript / css

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have that sneaking feeling I'm missing something obvious:

I ran

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

to precompile my assets before pushing to Heroku. Looking in `/public/assets` shows that `application.js` and `application.css` manifests successfully compiled, but **none of my standalone files precompiled**:

```
admin.js.coffee
blog.js.coffee.erb
[ ... several more similarly named ... ]
twitter.js.coffee.erb
```

and

```
admin.css.less
home.css.less
public.css.less
```

are all missing from `/public/assets`.

I thought that Rails would precompile the application.js/.css files, plus anything else that doesn't end in js/css:

> The default matcher for compiling files includes application.js,
>   application.css and all files that do not end in js or css:
>
> ```
> [ /\w+\.(?!js|css).+/, /application.(css|js)$/ ]
> ```

from: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

I don't want to have to manually update `config.assets.precompile` every time an asset file name changes. Am I missing something that will make Rails precompile these assets?

### Update

Based on @Richard Hulse's answer below, I tested it out by created a separate manifest file for a standalone asset (i.e. I renamed `twitter.js.coffee.erb` to `twitter-include.js.coffee.erb` and added `twitter.js` with a single `//= require` pulling in the renamed original). **This seems to work.**

**There must be a cleaner way than this**, and it seems to **contradict the Rails guide** quoted above. The guide says the only files that won't be compiled are .js or .css files **not** named `application`. What I'm see is **only** .js or .css being directly compiled (i.e. not via a manifest) - nothing else.

Comment: That default matcher is out of date; the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) now says: `[ Proc.new{ |path| !File.extname(path).in?(['.js', '.css']) }, /application.(css|js)$/ ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

If these files are included in your application manifests, then they are included in the site's application files.

There should be a line in both application manifests: `require_tree`, that will pick up all the assets automatically for your. Is that in these files?

Edit in reply to edit:

The way I would structure this is have two sets of manifests. The standard ones (application.css/.js) are for public. The admin set are for admin pages. Include all the stuff you want in admin.js/.css manifests and add those files to the precompile array:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css']
```

This would allow you to share code between the two groups. For example you can include jquery  in both, but jquery_ujs in admin only. In your admin section layout just include the admin manifests instead of the application manifests.

In practice you will then add new files to the application or admin manifests as you develop the site, and you won't have to change the precompile configuration.

Once you get to the point of adding lots of assets, an admin section and so on, it is expected that things will get more complex and that you have to be explicit about what is included in manifests and the order (as opposed to require_tree).

Comment: These files are not included in any manifest file (application.js/.css or otherwise). On your second point, wouldn't that concatenate the code directly into the application.js asset file? I don't want that. For example, I have page specific code in `admin.js.coffee` that shouldn't run on every page. Does this mean I need to create separate manifest files for every standalone asset?

Comment: So is the RoR guide incorrect then when it states that any non js/css files will be precompiled?

Comment: The precompile regex will get everything that does NOT have .js or .css in the filename. The exception are the application manifests.

Comment: I think I see my mistake - I thought it would compile everything that does not have .js or .css **as the last extension**. So I thought `foo.css.less` would be precompiled, but `foo.css` wouldn't. I should have taken a closer look at that regex

Comment: If it is application.anything_with_js_or_css_in_it then it gets compiled. So application.js.coffee.erb still gets compiled. And any non js and css files gets compiled. foo would not be compiled with css anywhere in the extension list. It was set up that way expecting the files to be included in the manifest via require_tree. It is kinda tricky to get your head around.